# Excel macro to combine workbooks, Runtime Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I am attempting to merge specific xls files into one sheet, but I get a runtime error 1004 saying " Copy method of Worksheet class failed" I am thinking this is because I am trying to merge over 100 files?

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Path = "C:\Users\..."
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*100.00mA.isd.xls")

Do While Filename <> ""

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    **Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)**
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it copy some sheets and then eventually fail? Or does it fail on the very first pass?

Comment: The number of sheets in an Excel workbook is based on the memory on your system.  How many sheets does it copy before it fails?

Comment: It just copies one sheet.

Comment: I think @DaveU nailed it. Your problem is using ActiveWorkbook. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) as well so you can improve other parts of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have occssionally run into a "timing" problem with xl2003 and `ActiveWorkbook`, maybe this is causing your problem.  Sometimes the VBA code gets to the `ActiveWorkbook` line before Excel has the new workbook fully opened, consequently, `ThisWorkbook` becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`.  The way to work around this is to specifically assign a variable to the new workbook.

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Dim wB As Workbook '<=New
    Path = "C:\Users\..."
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*100.00mA.isd.xls")

    Do While Filename <> ""

        Set wB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True) '<=New
        For Each Sheet In wB.Sheets '<=New
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
        wB.Close '<=New
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another situation, where the described runtime error will appear:

In the case that your target workbook is an Excel 97-2003 file (.xls) and your source workbook is an Excel 2007 (or higher) file (.xlsx).

Having this combination, the `sheet.copy` method will cause the same runtime error.

You may check the different workbook formats by reading the `ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat` property.