# Activeworkbook - error 91 - Object Variable or with block variable not set - in Workbook_open

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen several questions relating to Object variable not set when using Activeworkbook, but none for my particular scenario.  I use some code in workbook_open that tests a condition to decide if the user should be shown a form

`If Len(ActiveWorkbook.Names("DCStype_Selected").RefersToRange.Value) = 0 Then`

This works fine for most users 99% of the time.  However some users have reported error 91 - Object Variable  or with block variable not set, and it is on the activeworkbook line.
I believe I have tracked the scenario where this happens and it is always for users who do not have my excel workbook in a trusted location, and so are prompted to enable macros and this error occurs when they click the "enable" button.
Once I have talked them through setting a folder as a trusted location, and moving the workbook to that folder, this issue does not occur.

1. Could anyone tell me a more defensive way to code my line, so that it works regardless of a users security settings?
2. Could some one explain why this error only occurs in this specific scenario?

Comment: Not sure, but this may help.  Instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, assign the workbook to a variable when opening it, eg, `Set wB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)`, then test for wB.  See my  answer to a previous post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191731/excel-macro-to-combine-workbooks-runtime-error-1004/24195994#24195994)

Comment: @DaveU - Will explore this, but its not possible with that exact syntax.  This workbook is used by multiple customers across multiple locations, none of which are actually in our company, so I have no control over hardware, software, file locations etc.  So how to retrieve details of the current workbook without using "activeworkbook" seems to be my problem

Comment: Oh, I see.  Maybe another way would be to loop thru all the open workbooks and set wB to the workbook named "DCStype_Selected".  Then test wB and take appropriate action if wB = Nothing.

Comment: @DaveU - Thanks Dave, that sounds a good option

Answer (score 0):

I would set ActiveWorkbook.Names("DCStype_Selected").RefersToRange.Value as a variable and on error

- either set a message box to tell them to move the file to a trusted folder
- or set the variable to 0 to avert further damage and debug mode

  Sub ert()
  On Error GoTo Err
  ... 'your code
  If False Then
  Err:
  ... 'MsgBox or setting the var to 0
  End If
  End Sub

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really suitable.  I have extensive error handling already across all my modules, the process of explaining how to set trusted locations is not suitable for a message box.  I need the workbook object, so setting to 0 is not an option.  Think DaveU's comments is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I had the exact same problem... eventually got around it like this:

```
Dim wBook As Workbook

Do While wBook Is Nothing
    Set wBook = ActiveWorkbook
    DoEvents
    ' Prob. put a counter in here to prevent infinite looping...
Loop
```